# Why is this limit zero in this example in Spivak's calculus book?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I didn't understand this example in the [Spivak's calculus book](http://computo.fismat.umich.mx/~fhernandez/Cursos/Calculo2015/spivak.pdf) (page 413):

> At first sight this corollary appears to have unnecessarily complicated hypotheses; it might seem that the existence of the polynomial $P$ would automatically imply that $f$ is sufficiently differentiable for $P_{n,a,f}$ to exist.  But in fact this is not so.  For example (Figure 4), suppose that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{n+1},& x\text{ irrational}\\0,&x\text{ rational.}\end{cases}$$
>   If $P(x)=0$, then $P$ is certainly a polynomial of degree $\le n$ which equals $f$ up to order $n$ at $0$.  On the other hand, $f'(a)$ does not exist for any $a\neq0$, so $f''(0)$ is undefined.

He is saying this function $\frac{f(x)}{x^i}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for $0\le i\le n$. I reckon it's not true, see for example for $i=n$. For the limit of this function:

> $\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=x$, if $x$ is irrational and $0$, if $x$ is rational

is not zero as $x$ approaches to 0.

Comment: Why not? Both $x$ and $0$ tend to $0$ as $x\to0$, and $f(x)/x^n\le\max(x,0)$.

Comment: He is *not* saying that $f(x) /x^{i} =0$ for $0\leq i\leq n$, but rather saying that $f(x) /x^{i} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$ which is true. Also the limit in your last statement is $0$. Why do you think it should not be $0$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x^i}\right|<\epsilon\ \forall\ \epsilon>0,\ |x|<\epsilon^{1/(n+1-i)}$$

what can you conclude from this?

Comment: This is very bad notation. Acceptable on a blackboard, terrible in writing. At a glance, it is totally unclear what is the conclusion, what is quantified. Just spell it out.

Comment: @tomasz I obviously wasn't giving a full proof, but enough of a hint for the OP to figure it out him/her self

Comment: Just because you're not saying it all doesn't mean you can't say it in a clear way. I fully approve of not giving a full solution, what I don't approve of is bad style.

Comment: @tomasz hm, I thought it was pretty clear.  I'll wait for the OP's opinion or more people.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $g_i(x) = f(x)/x^i$ for $i=0,\dotsc,n$.  Then 
$$
g_i(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^{n+1-i} & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}\\
0 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\epsilon >0$ and pick $\delta = \min\{1,\epsilon\}>0$.  If $|x| < \delta$ then $|x| < 1$, so $|x^k| = |x|^k \le |x|$ for all $k \ge 1$.  Thus for $|x| <  \delta$ we have that $|g_i(x)| \le |x| < \delta \le \epsilon$.  Thus $g_i(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ for all $i=0,\dotsc,n$.